# I cant deploy a VS-2017 app(Android and IOS) to an iphone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to deploy an app to a iphone but it give the next warning:

> MTOUCH : warning MT0136: Cannot find the assembly
>   'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

**and then this error:**

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException', referenced from the
>   method 'System.Void
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException::.ctor(System.String)'
>   in 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

- I can run the app in simulator but no in a real device..
- I read that I have to add System.Configuration assembly but it doesn't appears in the options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually after you right click "references" in your project, "add references" and search for "configuration" it at the top right under the "Assemblies" tab you should find a reference called "System.Configuration" that you can add to your project.

Comment: I don't have System.Configuration, but this error appears when I have other projects using Entity Framework, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I have referenced an Assembly `"System.ServiceModel"` in my Xamarin Forms project. This causes this issue. I removed this assembly and installed `"System.ServiceModel.Security"` and `"System.ServiceModel.Http"` from `nuget` package.

This resolved my problem.